Shell how to pass only some user input to script?
If I have a very simple shell script like this:
echo "thing 1?"
read input1
echo $input1

echo "thing 2?"
read input2
echo $input2

How can I call the script/command with only 1 of the user inputs provided, while allowing any subsequent reads calls to prompt my terminal? I have been doing printf "foo\n" | sh myscript.sh which does pass in the 1st read, but then when it get's to the 2nd, instead of prompting the user the script just exits.

Use cat to read from standard input.
( echo foo; cat ) | sh myscript.sh


Wow. OK that does work. No idea you could use cat like that. What about with commands that have a more direct need for the terminal context? This broke when doing aws configure sso for example. I got BWARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR). and could no longer user arrow keys to select options from menus

What about them? As you stated, they need "direct need for the terminal". Usually such commands have command line flags for batch execution. Sso requires user interaction. There are also emulators like screen or tmux, and finally there is expect. Overall, i do not like interactive input.

UUOC -- useful use of cat!
